# Method for roll 5 dice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a game with 5 dice. I create a function for rolling the dice with random method but I don't know how I can expand this for the other four dice. I don't want to create a method for each die.

```
dice.component.html

 <button type="button" (click)="rollDie()">Roll the dice</button>

  <img [src]="path" alt="die-one" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="path" alt="die-two" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="path" alt="die-three" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="path" alt="die-four" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="path" alt="die-five" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="path" alt="die-six" class="img-fluid">


dice.component.ts

path = '/assets/img/die-one.png';
path1 = '/assets/img/die-one.png';
path2 = '/assets/img/die-two.png';
path3 = '/assets/img/die-three.png';
path4 = '/assets/img/die-four.png';
path5 = '/assets/img/die-five.png';
path6 = '/assets/img/die-six.png';


rollDie() {

let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

switch (number) {
  case 1:
    this.path = this.path1;
    break;
  case 2:
    this.path = this.path2;
        break;
  case 3:
    this.path = this.path3;
    break;
  case 4:
    this.path = this.path4;
    break;
  case 5:
    this.path = this.path5;
    break;
  case 6:
    this.path = this.path6;
}
}
```

Thank you !
:)

Comment: Note that `rollDie` is incorrect. `let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);` will give you the possible values 0, 1, ...6 (inclusive). (Note the `0`.) To get 1...6 (inclusive), use `let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;`

Comment: Also note that if you make your paths an array, `rollDie` gets *much* simpler: `var paths = ['/assets/img/die-one.png', /*...*/];` then `rollDie() { this.path = paths[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]; }` (note no `+ 1`, because we want the values 0...5 inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

You can set your function to return the number it generates and then call it 5 times into 5 different variables like:

`var die1 = rollDie(),
     die2 = rollDie(),
     //etc..`

**EDIT:** You can use another function in your click handler for example:

`<button type="button" (click)="btnHandler()">Roll the dice</button>`

And inside **btnHandler()** you can call **rollDie()** 5 times into 5 variables and you can do whatever you need later with those dice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
Finally I create something like that:

```
paths = ['/assets/img/die-one.png',
'/assets/img/die-two.png',
'/assets/img/die-three.png',
'/assets/img/die-four.png',
'/assets/img/die-five.png',
'/assets/img/die-six.png'];
path = [];

rollDie() {
this.path = Array.from({length: 6}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
}



  <img [src]="paths[path[0]]" alt="die-one" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="paths[path[1]]" alt="die-two" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="paths[path[2]]" alt="die-three" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="paths[path[3]]" alt="die-four" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="paths[path[4]]" alt="die-five" class="img-fluid">
  <img [src]="paths[path[5]]" alt="die-six" class="img-fluid">
```